# Groups that cover weighted set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, discrete-optimization, discrete-geometry

I am trying to find an efficient algorithm to give solutions to the following problem.

There is a set of unknown groups of elements $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$, etc. that together contain and cover a set of elements $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, $\ldots$
These groups share elements. Each element has associated a value between $0$ and $1$. So for example $e_1 = 0.4$ and $e_4 = 0.4$. Each group has associated a value from $0$ to $1$. So for example, $g_1 = 0.1$ and $g_3 = 0.4$. The group weights sum to $1$. That is $g_1 + g_2 + g_3 + \ldots = 1$.

I want to find the groups $g_1$, $g_2$, $\ldots$ and their respective weights such that

$$\sum_{\left\{i \,\mid\, e_j \in g_i\right\}} g_i = e_j$$

Mathematically speaking, if $E$ is a vector of the elements weights and $G$ is a vector of groups weights then I want to find a $0-1$ matrix $W$ and a positive real matrix $G$ such that $E = W G$ and $\textrm{sum}(G) = 1$

Going a bit further... If $E$ is now a matrix of elements values between $0$ and $1$, can I find a real positive matrix $G$ such that each column sums to $1$ and a $0-1$ matrix $W$ such that $E = W G$?

Comment: I've tried to improve the legibility, but I don't fully understand the question. For one thing, $G$ seems to have too many different meanings. For another, I'm not sure what the inputs to the problem are and what the outputs are. Are $e_j$ the only external constraints, and you can freely choose the $g_i$?

Comment: Clarification !

Inputs    e_1   e_2     e_3   e_4 e_5 etc. These are numbers between 0 and 1. Say, for example, 0.1   0.1  0.2   0.9  0.9.

Output    a set of groups and weights. Say   g1 = {e_1, e_3, e_4} with weight 0.1   g_2 = {e_2 , e_3, e_5} with weight 0.1 and g_3 = {e_4 , e_5} with weight 0.8.

The groups, together, contain all the elements e_1, e_2, ... , e_5. The weight of the groups sums to 1. The weight of all the groups that contain element e_i sum up to the value associated to e_i

Answer (score 1):

The first part is easy: suppose without loss of generality that $e_0 \le e_1 \le \ldots \le e_n$. Then let

- $g_1 = \{ e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n \}$ with weight $e_1$,
- $g_2 = \{ e_2, e_3, \ldots, e_n \}$ with weight $(e_2 - e_1)$,
- $\vdots$
- $g_{n+1} = \{ \}$ with weight $(1 - e_n)$

Note that this requires one more group than element. It can't be solved in general if the number of groups must be the same as the number of elements: an easy counterexample is the case with exactly one element $e$ where its weight is not $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Yes. It is not hard to come up with one solution.
Is there a way to list all the solutions or search through the space of solutions in an efficient way ?

Comment: Yes, there a way to find solutions with certain properties ?
For example, find one solution with less than x or find one solution where the groups cannot be nested ?